Prove that this double sum gives delta funtion in the limit
I stumbled upon this while solving a quantum mechanics problem.
Consider the following expression ($-L<x,x^\prime < L$):
$$f(x-x^\prime)=\frac{1}{2L}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n,m=-N}^{N}\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{L}\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)\left(n-m\right)\right) \tag{1}$$
Wolfram Alpha gives me:
$$\sum_{n,m=-N}^{N}\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{L}\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)\left(n-m\right)\right)=\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)}{L}\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)}{2L}\right)}$$
It's easy to check that:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)}{L}\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)}{2L}\right)}=\begin{cases}
0, & x\neq x^{\prime}\\
\infty, & x=x^{\prime}
\end{cases}$$
Numerically, Wolfram Alpha gives the following (I checked for multiple values of N and guessed the answer from that):
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)}{L}\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)}{2L}\right)}dx=2L$$
Which leads me to an assumption:
$$f(x-x^\prime)=\delta (x-x^\prime) \tag{2}$$
Are these steps enough to prove (2) and how to analytically prove the values for the sum and the integral provided by Wolfram Alpha?
Edit: fixed a small typo in the numerator sine argument.
I now have the proof for the double sum value, but it's very lengthy.

Those steps are unfortunately not enough to prove $f(x-x')=\delta(x-x').$ There might also be terms involving derivatives of $\delta$.
Let $f_N$ be the right hand side of (1) without $\lim_{N\to\infty},$ and let $\varphi$ be a test function. What we want to show is that
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \int f_N(x-x') \, \varphi(x') \, dx' = \varphi(x)
$$
without any terms involving derivatives of $\varphi$.

I see. I'll try the integration, perhaps a change of variable to x=t/N and Taylor expansion of $\varphi(t/N)$ should do the trick
